# Spotify Web Api Token Request Response 400

Tags: java, http, spotify

Right now I'm trying to exchange my authorization code to a token over the Authorization Code Flow method in the Spotify Web Api, but as Response I always get a 400 Status. Here's the code I'm using:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(new URI("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token/?grant_type=authorization_code&code=" + tempCode + "&redirect_uri=" + RedirectUri));
    httppost.addHeader("Authorization",  "Basic " + Base64.encodeBase64String((ClientId + ":" + ClientSecret).getBytes()));
    httppost.setProtocolVersion(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
```

Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the slash after token

it should be https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token

Also, the request parameters should be in the POST body instead of being in the URI.

Comment: Thanks, "fixes" this error. Now i get a proper response body. But it's still not working. It's 400 as Status and the body says: {"error":"server_error","error_description":"Unexpected status: 400"}

Comment: Well you are posting so you should put all the request parameters in the POST body instead of putting them in the URI. Your POST URI should only be https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token. Do you understand?

Comment: Thank you! Dumb me not thought about that. Now it's all working! :)